# Tips for getting the Reins of the Drake of the West Wind as fast as possible

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm working on my dailies to get `Tol Barad Commendations` so I can eventually pick up a `Reins of the Drake of the West Wind`. It seems after one day of dailies, I got 6 commendations. The mount requires 200. My question is, is there an ideal way to get these things faster? One of the quests is `Victory in Tol Barad`. I've never done PvP before but it gives 3 commendations. Do I need to get PvP gear to do this? What's the easiest way to get this done without repeatedly getting ganked?

Any and all advice to speed up the progress of getting Tol Barad Commendations including advice for the Victory in Tol Barad quest are highly appreciated.

Comment: [Reins of the Drake of the West Wind](http://www.wowhead.com/item=63039)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to get 18 commendations per day plus 3 commendations per week, bringing the time to get the mount down to about 11 days of luck and persistence.

First, make sure you are doing the [Victory in Tol Barad](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=28882) quest each week. You don't have to be a PvP master to do this quest, just make sure your in the zone during the battle and (optionally, for the sake of your realmmates) assist however you can.

There are then a total of 18 daily quests for 1 token each that you can do. However, reaching all 18 will require you to cycle Tol Barad victories.

First, make sure you are doing the 6 dailies outside of the PvP zone. These will always be available and never change for a guaranteed 6 tokens per day.

Now, when your faction controls Tol Barad, there is three more quests available in the PvP zone guaranteed:

- [Swamp Bait](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=28162)
- [The Leftovers](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=28163)
- [A Huge Problem](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=28122)

Each time Tol Barad resets, there will be a second NPC quest giver in the PvP zone who rotates available quests. There are 3 different sets of 3 quests, all involving the area outside of Baradin Hold. This guy will randomly cycle each victory you get, so it is pure luck.

So that is:

- 6 Commendations each day for quests in the PvE side of Tol Barad
- 3 Commendations in the PvP side of Tol Barad
- 3 sets of 3 Commendations randomly chosen in the PvP side of Tol Barad

18 commendations per day, plus 3 commendations per week.

(Side note: don't be afraid of the "PvP" side of Tol Barad, no actual PvP goes on when the battle isn't live, the opposite faction has no purpose to be there except for the occasional griefing).

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborate, well thought out answer. Dare I ask one more question? Where exactly is the PvP side of Tol Barad? Thank you.

Comment: [Tol Barad Penisula](http://www.wowpedia.org/File:WorldMap-TolBarad_Peninsula.jpg?c=1) is the PvE zone, and where you portal into, taking the giant bridge between faction camps to the south puts you in [Tol Barad](http://www.wowpedia.org/File:WorldMap-TolBarad.jpg?c=1) (PvP zone). You are taken directly to the PvP zone if you accept a PvP battle.

Comment: If your faction has control of Tol Borad and time is running out, do Tol Borad dailies before the Tol Borad Peninsula dailies. Just a reminder that TB quest givers disappear 15 minutes before the next fight starts.

Of the 6 TB dailies, do the 3 cycling dailies before the 3 fixed dailies as you will be unable to complete or turn them in once faction control is over.

Answer (score 0):

Remember other than the actual PvP battle for Tol Barad you DON'T have to pvp or be flagged for pvp.

If your side control Tol Barad you can enter at any time by riding over the bridge. Go to the controlled central zone and you will have 2 NPC's that will give 3 daily quests each. One NPC will ALWAYS spawn and the 3 quests Swamp Bail, Huge Problim and Leftovers are always there (unless you have completed them already that day). The other NPC will give 3 random quests (out of 9 possible).

If on your server Tol Barad passes back and forth quite a bit check the NPC respawn for the next 3 quests you have not yet done.

As Resorath says you can get 18 tokens per day if you do every quest available. It does restrict your other dailys a little (if your also doing Molten Front) but the drake looks great and it's worth getting.